# Pandas Attribute error: Nonetype has no attribute rename

Tags: python, pandas

learning this from a tutorial, the code isn't working on my machine. error in line with df.rename

```
def compile_data():
colist = pd.read_csv("nse500symbolistnov2020.csv")
tickers = colist['Symbol']

maindf = pd.DataFrame()

for count,ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    df = df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
    df = df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker},inplace=True)
    df.drop(['Open','High','Low','CLose','Volume'],1,inplace=True)

    if maindf.empty:
        maindf = df
    else:
        maindf = maindf.join(df, how='outer')

    if count % 10 == 0:
        print(count)

print(maindf.head())
maindf.to_csv('NSE60joined.csv')
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Try removing inplace=True from that line with .rename

Comment: If your question has been answered you should accept the best answer to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the line

```
df = df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
```

Either remove inplace=True, or remove the assignment df =, leaving just

```
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
```

The same goes for the next line. Either use inplace=True, or assign the new dataframe to df, not both.

Comment: This is because using `inplace` changes the object in memory but returns `None`, whereas without `inplace`, the same change is applied to the input object but the changed object is returned.

Comment: thanks a lot. it is fixed by removing the inplace from set index.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `inplace=True` and want to see it's contents, it would return `None` as they merely mutate the DF instead of creating a new copy of it. Basically, you're assigning `None` to the result and hence it complains of the `AttributeError` as it isn't a df.DataFrame object anymore to access it's `.head()` method.

You can do it now in two ways:

*No assigning with inplace parameter*

```
df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker},inplace=True)
```

*assign without inplace parameter*

```
df= df.rename(columns={'Y':l})
```